# Version 29 of the SDK can't be downloaded

Tags: android-studio, sdk

In my Android Studio the last available SDK is **v28**.

How can I download Android SDK **v29**? Is not on the list.

**Also**, in the **Android Studio Settings -> System Settings -> Updates**, I'm on the **stable** channel and the current **Android Studio version is 3.1.4**, **Android SDK Tools version is 26.1.1** and the **Android Platform version number is API 28 revision 6**.

Comment: Why do you want to download a SDK comes from the **future**?

Comment: Wow! My mistake... I thinking PIE SDK version was 29, but it 28... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are the man coming from the future.

At now (2019-01-04T01:12+0800), [Android SDK repository](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml) just have the tools up to API 28 (search for "android-28" or "android-29"), the latest public release of Android is just also Android Pie (API 28), [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) or [from Android official website](https://www.android.com/).

Some recent report has indicated the presence of API 29 (Android Q), for example this [news from XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-skip-android-9-1-pie-android-q/), or [AOSP sources](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/bionic/+/742226/1/docs/status.md#40). However there are no public announcement of Android Q release at this time.

Maybe, in the future, the link for [Android SDK Platform 29 rev 1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r01.zip) will come true :-)

Comment: The link works, so I guess we're in the future now.